# asp.net mvc routing with multiple optional parameters did not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I wrote a attribute route `Route("Home/{category?}/{Subcategory?}/List")` want to match the following examples
`/Home/C1/S1/List`, `/Home/C1/List`, `/Home/List`

But only to match the first url, the optional parameter did not work.
How to use a routing rule matches the above three examples?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("Home/{category?}/{subcategory?}/List")]
    public IActionResult List(Category? category = null, SubCategory? subcategory = null)
    {
        return Content(category.ToString() + "/" + subcategory.ToString());
    }

    [Route("Home/{code}/Detail")]
    public IActionResult Detail(string code)
    {
        return Content(code);
    }
}


public enum Category
{
    C1,
    C2,
    C3,
    C4
}

public enum SubCategory
{
    S1,
    S2,
    S3,
    S4
}
```

Similar Questions

[Routing optional parameters in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678045/routing-optional-parameters-in-asp-net-mvc-5)

[MVC routing with one fixed action and controllers with multiple optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449481/mvc-routing-with-one-fixed-action-and-controllers-with-multiple-optional-paramet)

Comment: Optional parameters should be in the last. You cannot insert optional parameters between the non-optional parameters as you did in the List action.

Answer (score 18):

If a route does not work, it can be done using three routing rules.

```
[Route("Home/List")]
[Route("Home/{category}/List")]
[Route("Home/{category}/{subcategory}/List")]
```

thx all.

Answer (score 5):

You may only have one optional parameter per route, and that optional parameter must be the last parameter.

see
https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-core-demystified-routing-in-mvc/